# latest Book (2018/19) for Computer Science for Grade 2 to 8 students

Tags: textbook

I am currently looking for what book to use/adapt for the 2019-2020 school year for students Grade 2 to 8 ICGSE or CBSE or other pattern.

Comment: You need to say a lot more about your goals for these students. I assume they aren't the same for every level. Eighth graders, for example, have more (and different) cognitive ability than second graders.

Comment: What sort of topic do you want to teach? There are a whole range of resources out there, and we'd be much more helpful if you could specify what you're looking for a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. My expectation is latest computer science book which you know for student on any grade with in Grade 2 and Grade 8 ICGSE or CBSE or other pattern

Comment: @lahith I added your latest comment to the question. It does not add much. I will vote to close, until you address the comments above. (Note I do not know ICGSE etc. so help me out).

Answer (score 2):

Since you are asking about a wide range of ages, let me suggest that no single book is likely to do the job for you.

Instead, let me suggest a web site [CS Unplugged](https://csunplugged.org/en/) which uses non computer resources to teach simple concepts of CS, including Computational Thinking.

The main idea is that many things, including toys, can give youngsters appropriate metaphors that will bring them to a mindset that helps them later learn things more formally.

You can also do an online search for *Computational Thinking*, which will reveal a large number of resources, some (not all) of which will be appropriate for you.

I wouldn't try at this level, to focus very much on computer programming, though [Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu) is directed at youngsters.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed response. My expectation is latest computer science book/online resource  which you know for student level. CS unplugged looks nice but it is mostly up to the age of 10 years.